# display special price's end date to my product page in opencart

Tags: php, date, opencart

Is there any way I could display the special price's end date on my product page in opencart 1.5.5.1 if an end date is set?

I added this to my catalog/controller/product/product.php:

```
$special_info = $this->db->query("SELECT date_end FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
         if ($special_info->num_rows) {
            $date_end = $special_info->row['date_end'];   
              $this->data['date_end'] = date($this->language->get('date_format_short'), strtotime($date_end));
         }else{
               $this->data['date_end'] = '';
         }
```

and to my catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/product.tpl this:

```
Special Ends: <?php echo $date_end; ?>
```

but it doesn't seem to work very well. I see the date if I set a date to a special product, but if I don't, it still shows this: **30.11.-0001**

How can I make it display nothing if an end date is not set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are just getting a special for a product, regardless of if it's actually in date or for that customer group. The full query used to get a special is in `/catalog/model/catalog/product.php`

```
(SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special
```

So you need to add that to your query as well and supply the customer group id. You also need to check that the date isn't `0000-00-00` so your full code should look as follows

```
$this->data['date_end'] = '';

$customer_group_id = $this->customer->isLogged() ? $this->customer->getCustomerGroupId() : $this->config->get('config_customer_group_id');
$special_info = $this->db->query("SELECT date_end FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND customer_group_id ='" . (int) $customer_group_id . "' AND ((date_start = '0000-00-00' OR date_start < NOW()) AND (date_end = '0000-00-00' OR date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY priority ASC, price ASC LIMIT 1");

if ($special_info->num_rows && $special_info->row['date_end'] != '0000-00-00') {
    $this->data['date_end'] = date($this->language->get('date_format_short'), strtotime($special_info->row['date_end']));
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work I'm afraid. I replaced my line of code with yours and nothing changed